# Finding points on any function at an equal distance

Tags: functions, visualization

I'm developing an app to visualize mathematical functions in a coordinate system. I'm calculating $y$ for every pixel along the $x$ axis. This method works well with basic functions, like $f(x) = x$ or $sin(x)$ but only renders a few points when the function is $100x$ or $sin(10x)$.

So basically, I want to calculate $y$ more densely at places where the function is steeper. I would hope to find a universal solution, as the function could be anything the user provides.

This image illustrates my problem well, but I'm not sure if Chebyshev nodes are the right way to go as I only have a surface level knowledge regarding functions.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqI3l.png

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity: the wording of the question is quite clear as it stands. The image is useful supporting information for those who can view it and that is perfectly appropriate. Images are **not** banned on MSE.

Comment: The image (I can view it, so my compliant is out of principle) changed my understanding of the question, so I'll claim it is important.